# FFMPEG clogs up all the traffic

Tags: java, spring, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming

The problem is this. I have a video file (it is in /mnt/....) on remote storage. When I run the command to copy it FFMPEG clogs the entire internet stream. Apparently when converting the video it copies it first. Because of this the whole application is temporarily unavailable.

**I need to limit the baud rate for this task.**

I am thinking to solve this problem by reading into BufferStream (or something else) and manually putting the stream into FFMPEG stdin.
But I can't find any example code where stream is put into FFMPEG .
This may not be the best solution, but I have to limit the speed of copying from remote storage.
I would be very happy with Java code examples

I invoke MMPEG like this

```
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                getFfmpegPath(),
                "-safe", "0",
                "-protocol_whitelist", "pipe,file",
                "-y", "-f", "concat",
                "-i", "-",
                "-c", "copy",
                destination.toString()
        );
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)
```

Comment: `pv -L` might be useful

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What is it, how do you use it?

Comment: It was for using in a pipe.  After closer inspection of your command it looks like you provide input to the FFMMPEG process yourself?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The startup line was before me, I'm fixing a problem that now exists.  I didn't really see how this would help me. Could you add a little bit of information

Comment: Also, I do not understand how to indicate that I use a stream. After all, in the line I must necessarily specify the file in the parameter -i

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do -and what clogging  means but lets  assume  you mean "the  thing aint working" - look  up  the usage of   ffmpeg- as far as i can recall the -i -   means  stdin or so, b) -f concat means youre gonna give it a file after   that etc  -- maybe  the commands have changed or maybe you  are short  on  knowledge  of  ffmpeg.